# Dynamodb table: key schema validation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, amazon-dynamodb

Title: Dynamodb table validation error

Here is my code.

```
const updateParams = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
        Key: {
          'partitionKey': item.partitionKey,
          'sortKey': item.sortKey,
      'couponID': item.couponID,
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'set field = :field',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ':field': fieldValue 
        }
    await docClient.update(updateParams).promise();
}
```

But I encountered an issue below.

> Error updating job records: ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

I have been struggling with it for 3 days but couldn't solve it.
I hope someone help me to fix this issue.

Google
I'm expecting someone help me to fix that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand why you added `couponID`. There can't be several records with same `partitionKey` and `sortKey` in DynamoDB table. It must be unique.
Remove `couponID` and try it once more.

Comment: wow.
you are a really pro.
thanks for your efforts.